# How to match against end-of-file?

Tags: eof, ragel

I want to match either newline ("\n"), semi-colon (";") or eof as being a valid end of statement. The first two are obvious, e.g.

```
eos = "\n" | ";";
```

but I'm not sure how to also match against the eof in the same way.

Is there some way to match against eof? I wondered if `empty` would work but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: It depends on how your ragel lexer is structured and what you're doing with it. If you're passing an EOS token off to be parsed elsewhere, you could manually send an EOS token when the input is finished.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock that's not a stupid idea. I was just hoping I could match against `eof` but it seems like I'll need to send a token. The main reason is to have queued actions execute e.g. `fret` and so on. I want to have `eof` be an actual state so that transition actions can execute.

Comment: ragel has EOF actions - See 3.2.2 in the User Guide.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock yes, I've been looking at that, but I can't see how to make it work like a state transition. e.g. on eof take this transition to an accepting state, which would also execute all actions on that transition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small machine with an action on the end-of-statement terminator or EOF.

```
%%{
    machine test;

    eos = (';' | '\n') ${ /* terminator code here */ } >eof{ /* eof code here */ };
    main := ('a' 'b' eos)*;

    write data;
    write init;
    write exec;

}%%
```

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. So, I tried this approach, but it's not easy to use when you embed actions into main. I will have to try it out again and see if something like this can work, but I suspect I need to actually have some kind of state transition, not just "Do this action on EOF".